# Good approach to resizing 'main' parent table columns in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2014 database that essentially consists of a main table and a few child tables that have foreign key relationships with it.  They in turn have their own child tables.  In terms of SQL complexity this DB is nothing special (no BLOB fields either) and the size of it on disk is less than 50 MB.

However, one of the columns in this main table needs to be resized, from nvarchar(500) to nvarchar(MAX).  I'm unable to edit it in SSMS and am told I need to drop and re-create the table.

I know I can use the `Generate Scripts` option in SSMS to re-create and repopulate the database, but that seems like overkill?

I'd really like to turn off any constraints involving that main table, drop and recreate it with the new column size, reload its data from a script and then turn on those constraints again.  However, we're now getting into hazy bits of my SQL expertise and I'm not sure how best to do a limited maneuver like that and would love suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ALTER TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) command to resize the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL -- Or NOT NULL, as required
```

As per documentation on **Changing the Size of a Column**:

> You can change the length, precision, or scale of a column by
>   specifying a new size for the column data type in the ALTER COLUMN
>   clause. If data exists in the column, the new size cannot be smaller
>   than the maximum size of the data.

Comment: I'll be a son of a gun, I got so sidetracked by that SSMS warning that I didn't even try this.  Worked great, thank you.